# How to get unique values from list of list and store in set by using streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have classes `Employee` and `Address` as follows:

```
public static class Employee {
    private List<Address> address;
    
    // getters, etc.
}

public static class Address {
    private String city;
    
    // getters, etc.
}
```

I am learning streams, I am trying to iterate over the objects from list of list and create a set of unique values. I was able to get it working by using nested for loop. How can I convert below code to streams?

```
public static Set<String> getCityUniquName(List<Employee> emp){

    Set<String> cityUniquName = new HashSet<>();
    for(Employee e: emp){
        List<Address> addList = e.getAddress();
        for(Address add: addList){
            cityUniquName.add(add.getCity());
        }
    }
   return cityUniquName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [flatMap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap#map-and-flatmap-in-streams) to flatten the `Address` list and then use `map` to get the city from each `Address` object and then  collect into `Set`

```
Set<String> cityUniquName = emp.stream()
                .map(Employee::getAddress)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(Address::getCity)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each `Employee` is associated with a collection of `Address` instances, you need to apply of the stream operations that allow to flatten the data, namely either `flatMap()`, or `mapMulty()`.

***Note** that `flatMap()` expects a function producing a `Stream`,**not** a Collection like shown in another answer.*

## [Stream.flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function))

To turn a Stream of `Employee` into a Stream of `Address` in the *mapper* function of `flatMap()` we need to extract the collection of addresses and create a stream over it.

The only thing left is to get the city name and collect the result into a set.

```
public static Set<String> getCityUniqueName(List<Employee> emp) {
    
    return emp.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getAddress().stream())
        .map(Address::getCity)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

## [Stream.mapMulti](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer))

`mapMulti()` expects a [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html), which in turn takes two arguments: stream element (*having an initial type*) and a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html) of the resulting type. Every object offered to the consumer would appear in the resulting stream.

```
public static Set<String> getCityUniqueName1(List<Employee> emp) {
    
    return emp.stream()
        .<Address>mapMulti((e, c) -> e.getAddress().forEach(c))
        .map(Address::getCity)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```